# why does the PrimeNg pSortableColumn has no click events for container items?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I have used the Primng Table component and used the pSortableColumn so that it raises the event to sort the table. Inside the TH I have a component which has the header text and an icon to denote that it is asc or desc order.

**The problem is that it works when I click on the background  of the TH but when I click on any element of my component it does not register the event.**

[image: pSortableColumn click area]

The table component is housed in our own company search component but it works on the example website (which we use when developing component before sending to NPM.

But it seem that when I deploy to a real application its seems to behave differently.

I'm not sure if I am missing a reference but I have no warnings. Has anyone ever seen this behaviour before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this issue.

The solution was to update the primng npm package from 9.0.0 to 9.0.6

```
npm install primeng@9.0.6
```